# How Do I Stop MATE From Switching Windows When I Middle-Click the Title Bar?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, user-interface, mate

When I middle-click a tab in Chrome it closes it, which is handy.  However, if I try to middle-click a tab in Chrome and miss by 1 pixel, I wind up middle-clicking on the title bar, which for some reason causes MATE to act almost as if I'd done `ALT` + `TAB` (ie. it switches to the window behind it).

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I was writing this question I found an answer.  Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a way to solve this problem in the GUI, but at the command line I was able to run:

```
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.general action-middle-click-titlebar none
```

to fix the problem.

It works as follow:

`gsettings set` = command to change a "g" ie. GNOME (ie. MATE) setting

`org.mate.Marco.general` = "schema" (ie. settings category) for general MATE UI settings

`action-middle-click-titlebar` = setting that controls what happens when a window's title bar gets middle-clicked

You then have have several options you can set it to:

- `toggle_shade`
- `toggle_maximize`
- `toggle_maximize_horizontally`
- `toggle_maximize_vertically`
- `minimize`
- `none` = what I set it to to fix things (by making middle clicks do nothing)
- `lower` = what I had it set to: makes the window "lower" itself behind the window behind it (similar to `ALT` + `TAB`)
- `menu`
- `last`

Comment: This works. Note you can also use dconf or the gui, dconf-editor, to make this change.

`dconf write /org/mate/marco/general/action-middle-click-titlebar "'none'"`

Note the quoting around the value is required!